# How do I set invoice_payment_term_id required in Odoo 13?

Tags: html, required, qwebview, odoo-13

I am trying to set invoice_payment_term_id field as required. Usually just adding required="1" should work but not here:

```
                            <!-- Invoice payment terms (only invoices) + due date (only invoices / receipts) -->
                            <label for="invoice_payment_term_id" attrs="{'invisible': [('type', 'not in', ('out_invoice', 'out_refund', 'in_invoice', 'in_refund', 'out_receipt', 'in_receipt'))]}"/>
                            <div class="d-flex" attrs="{'invisible': [('type', 'not in', ('out_invoice', 'out_refund', 'in_invoice', 'in_refund', 'out_receipt', 'in_receipt'))]}">
                                <field name="invoice_payment_term_id" placeholder="Terms" attrs="{'invisible': [('type', 'not in', ('out_invoice', 'out_refund', 'in_invoice', 'in_refund', 'out_receipt', 'in_receipt'))]}"/>
                                <span class="o_form_label mx-3 oe_edit_only" attrs="{'invisible': [ '|', '|', '|', ('state', '!=', 'draft'), ('invoice_payment_term_id', '!=', False), ('type', 'not in', ('out_invoice', 'out_refund', 'in_invoice', 'in_refund', 'out_receipt', 'in_receipt'))]}"> or </span>
                                <field name="invoice_date_due" force_save="1" placeholder="Date" attrs="{'invisible': ['|', ('invoice_payment_term_id', '!=', False), ('type', 'not in', ('out_invoice', 'out_refund', 'in_invoice', 'in_refund', 'out_receipt', 'in_receipt'))]}"/>
                            </div>
```

I have tried:

```
<field name="invoice_payment_term_id" placeholder="Terms" required="1" attrs="{'invisible': [('type', 'not in', ('out_invoice', 'out_refund', 'in_invoice', 'in_refund', 'out_receipt', 'in_receipt'))]}"/>
```

and

```
<field name="invoice_payment_term_id" placeholder="Terms" attrs="{'invisible': [('type', 'not in', ('out_invoice', 'out_refund', 'in_invoice', 'in_refund', 'out_receipt', 'in_receipt'))], 'required': [('type', 'not in', 'in_refund')]}"/>
```

By the way, 'not in', 'in_refund' is just a modifier to try to get it running but can be any other modifier you like.

Per @Mayur Jotaniya following is the whole code:

````
<t t-name="account.report_invoice_document">
            <t t-call="web.external_layout">
                <t t-set="o" t-value="o.with_context(lang=lang)"/>
                <t t-set="address">
                    <address t-field="o.partner_id" t-options="{&quot;widget&quot;: &quot;contact&quot;, &quot;fields&quot;: [&quot;address&quot;, &quot;name&quot;], &quot;no_marker&quot;: True}"/>
                    <div t-if="o.partner_id.vat" class="mt16">
                        <t t-if="o.company_id.country_id.vat_label" t-esc="o.company_id.country_id.vat_label" id="inv_tax_id_label"/>
                        <t t-else="">Tax ID</t>: <span t-field="o.partner_id.vat"/></div>
                </t>
                <div class="page">
                    <h2>
                        <span t-if="o.type == 'out_invoice' and o.state == 'posted'">Invoice</span>
                        <span t-if="o.type == 'out_invoice' and o.state == 'draft'">Draft Invoice</span>
                        <span t-if="o.type == 'out_invoice' and o.state == 'cancel'">Cancelled Invoice</span>
                        <span t-if="o.type == 'out_refund'">Credit Note</span>
                        <span t-if="o.type == 'in_refund'">Vendor Credit Note</span>
                        <span t-if="o.type == 'in_invoice'">Vendor Bill</span>
                        <span t-if="o.name != '/'" t-field="o.name"/>
                    </h2>

                    <div id="informations" class="row mt32 mb32">
                        <div class="col-auto mw-100 mb-2" t-if="o.invoice_date" name="invoice_date">
                            <strong>Invoice Date:</strong>
                            <p class="m-0" t-field="o.invoice_date"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-auto mw-100 mb-2" t-if="o.invoice_date_due and o.type == 'out_invoice' and o.state == 'posted'" name="due_date">
                            <strong>Due Date:</strong>
                            <p class="m-0" t-field="o.invoice_date_due"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-auto mw-100 mb-2" t-if="o.invoice_origin" name="origin">
                            <strong>Source:</strong>
                            <p class="m-0" t-field="o.invoice_origin"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-auto mw-100 mb-2" t-if="o.partner_id.ref" name="customer_code">
                            <strong>Customer Code:</strong>
                            <p class="m-0" t-field="o.partner_id.ref"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-auto mw-100 mb-2" t-if="o.ref" name="reference">
                            <strong>Reference:</strong>
                            <p class="m-0" t-field="o.ref"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <t t-set="display_discount" t-value="any([l.discount for l in o.invoice_line_ids])"/>

                    <table class="table table-sm o_main_table" name="invoice_line_table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <!-- TODO: remove in master -->
                                <t t-set="colspan" t-value="6"/>
                                <th name="th_description" class="text-left"><span>Description</span></th>
                                <th name="th_source" class="d-none text-left"><span>Source Document</span></th>
                                <th name="th_quantity" class="text-right"><span>Quantity</span></th>
                                <th name="th_priceunit" t-attf-class="text-right {{ 'd-none d-md-table-cell' if report_type == 'html' else '' }}"><span>Unit Price</span></th>
                                <th name="th_price_unit" t-if="display_discount" t-attf-class="text-right {{ 'd-none d-md-table-cell' if report_type == 'html' else '' }}">
                                    <span>Disc.%</span>
                                    <!-- TODO: remove in master -->
                                    <t t-set="colspan" t-value="colspan+1"/>
                                </th>
                                <th name="th_taxes" t-attf-class="text-left {{ 'd-none d-md-table-cell' if report_type == 'html' else '' }}"><span>Taxes</span></th>
                                <th name="th_subtotal" class="text-right">
                                    <span groups="account.group_show_line_subtotals_tax_excluded">Amount</span>
                                    <span groups="account.group_show_line_subtotals_tax_included">Total Price</span>
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody class="invoice_tbody">
                            <t t-set="current_subtotal" t-value="0"/>

                            <t t-foreach="o.invoice_line_ids" t-as="line">

                                <t t-set="current_subtotal" t-value="current_subtotal + line.price_subtotal" groups="account.group_show_line_subtotals_tax_excluded"/>
                                <t t-set="current_subtotal" t-value="current_subtotal + line.price_total" groups="account.group_show_line_subtotals_tax_included"/>

                                <tr t-att-class="'bg-200 font-weight-bold o_line_section' if line.display_type == 'line_section' else 'font-italic o_line_note' if line.display_type == 'line_note' else ''">
                                    <t t-if="not line.display_type" name="account_invoice_line_accountable">
                                        <td name="account_invoice_line_name"><span t-field="line.name"/></td>
                                        <td class="text-right">
                                            <span t-field="line.quantity"/>
                                            <span t-field="line.product_uom_id" groups="uom.group_uom"/>
                                        </td>
                                        <td t-attf-class="text-right {{ 'd-none d-md-table-cell' if report_type == 'html' else '' }}">
                                            <span t-field="line.price_unit"/>
                                        </td>
                                        <td t-if="display_discount" t-attf-class="text-right {{ 'd-none d-md-table-cell' if report_type == 'html' else '' }}">
                                            <span t-field="line.discount"/>
                                        </td>
                                        <td t-attf-class="text-left {{ 'd-none d-md-table-cell' if report_type == 'html' else '' }}">
                                            <span t-esc="', '.join(map(lambda x: (x.description or x.name), line.tax_ids))" id="line_tax_ids"/>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="text-right o_price_total">
                                            <span t-field="line.price_subtotal" groups="account.group_show_line_subtotals_tax_excluded"/>
                                            <span t-field="line.price_total" groups="account.group_show_line_subtotals_tax_included"/>
                                        </td>
                                    </t>
                                    <t t-if="line.display_type == 'line_section'">
                                        <td colspan="99">
                                            <span t-field="line.name"/>
                                        </td>
                                        <t t-set="current_section" t-value="line"/>
                                        <t t-set="current_subtotal" t-value="0"/>
                                    </t>
                                    <t t-if="line.display_type == 'line_note'">
                                        <td colspan="99">
                                            <span t-field="line.name"/>
                                        </td>
                                    </t>
                                </tr>

                                <t t-if="current_section and (line_last or o.invoice_line_ids[line_index+1].display_type == 'line_section')">
                                    <tr class="is-subtotal text-right">
                                        <td colspan="99">
                                            <strong class="mr16">Subtotal</strong>
                                            <span t-esc="current_subtotal" t-options="{&quot;widget&quot;: &quot;monetary&quot;, &quot;display_currency&quot;: o.currency_id}"/>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </t>
                            </t>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                    <div class="clearfix">
                        <div id="total" class="row">
                            <div t-attf-class="#{'col-4' if report_type != 'html' else 'col-sm-7 col-md-5'} ml-auto">
                                <table class="table table-sm;page-break-inside: avoid;">
                                    <tr class="border-black o_subtotal" style="">
                                        <td><strong>Subtotal</strong></td>
                                        <td class="text-right">
                                            <span t-field="o.amount_untaxed"/>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <t t-foreach="o.amount_by_group" t-as="amount_by_group">
                                        <tr style="">
                                            <t t-if="len(o.line_ids.filtered(lambda line: line.tax_line_id)) == 1 and o.amount_untaxed == amount_by_group[2]">
                                                <td><span t-esc="amount_by_group[0]"/></td>
                                                <td class="text-right o_price_total">
                                                    <span t-esc="amount_by_group[3]"/>
                                                </td>
                                            </t>
                                            <t t-else="">
                                                <td>
                                                    <span t-esc="amount_by_group[0]"/>
                                                    <span>&amp;nbsp;<span>on</span>
                                                        <t t-esc="amount_by_group[4]"/>
                                                    </span>
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="text-right o_price_total">
                                                    <span t-esc="amount_by_group[3]"/>
                                                </td>
                                            </t>
                                        </tr>
                                    </t>
                                    <tr class="border-black o_total">
                                        <td><strong>Total</strong></td>
                                        <td class="text-right">
                                            <span t-field="o.amount_total"/>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <p t-if="o.type in ('out_invoice', 'in_refund')">
                        Please use the following communication for your payment : <b><span t-field="o.invoice_payment_ref"/></b>
                    </p>
                    <p t-if="o.narration" name="comment">
                        <span t-field="o.narration"/>
                    </p>
                    <p t-if="o.invoice_payment_term_id" name="payment_term">
                        <span t-field="o.invoice_payment_term_id.note"/>
                    </p>
                    <p t-if="o.fiscal_position_id.note" name="note">
                        <span t-field="o.fiscal_position_id.note"/>
                    </p>
                    <div id="qrcode" t-if="(o.company_id.qr_code) and (o.currency_id.name == 'EUR') and (o.invoice_partner_bank_id.acc_number != False)">
                        <p t-if="(o.invoice_partner_bank_id.qr_code_valid)">
                            <strong class="text-center">Scan me with your banking app.</strong><br/><br/>
                            <img class="border border-dark rounded" t-att-src="o.invoice_partner_bank_id.build_qr_code_url(o.amount_residual,(o.ref) if (o.ref) else o.name)"/>
                        </p>
                        <p t-if="(o.invoice_partner_bank_id.qr_code_valid == False)">
                            <strong class="text-center">The SEPA QR Code informations are not set correctly.</strong><br/>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </t>
        </t>```
````

Comment: Can you please add more code of your XML file for better understand what actually missing in your code?

Comment: @MayurJotaniya thanks, I believe it will be too much code for here without much further info but here it goes:

Comment: You can declare your field `required='True'` in `.py` file. So, it will always be required in your template.

Comment: Ok, I added it to the account_move.py as required=True and solved it. Now I will have to remember to add it again after any update. Appreciate your support.